# Login Script Issues

Tags: php

Hi guys im having an issue with my login scipt on line 44 (i will mark it). If someone could help me out it would be much appreciated. Its to do with the else statement on line 44. Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = $_POST['email'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password){

$connect = mysql_connect("*****", "******", "*******") or die("Couldnt Connect to the Database");
mysql_select_db("1619882_members") or die("Couldnt Select/find the Database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM social WHERE email='$email'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows!==0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $dbusername = $row['email'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }

    if($username==$dbusername&&sha1($password)==$dbpassword){

        echo "you are in";
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    }
    else{
        echo "Your password is incorrect!";
        }

    (line 44) else{
        die("That user does not exist!");
            }


else
    die("Please enter a username and Password!!");  


?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /srv/disk1/1619882/www/connect-freely.com/login.php on line 44   This is the error

Comment: Dude, EVERYTHING is your script is horrible. Everything. Why the hell are you trying to build this by yourself ? mysql_query is outdated for 5+ years, your SQL is open for even the most simple injection attacks, the system itself makes no sense, you have useless words in there that have nothing to do with PHP and its syntax... SHA1 is not for password hashing. And in general, why are you working with a text editor that doesn't even check your syntax ?

Comment: I didnt ask for help not judgement...

Comment: You can't have two elses for one if.

Comment: How could i have it so that if the email doesnt exist in the Database echo the user doesnt exist

Comment: @j08691: My ex-wife thought she could.

Comment: You're forgetting to close ``if($numrows!==0){``. Besides you're checking for ``$username`` but only setting the variables ``$email`` and ``$password``

Comment: @user3329680 You cannot use this on a real server! Seriously.

Comment: well if you could point me to a secure login script tutorial it would be appreciated !

Comment: @Panique The [MySQL extension is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) as of [version 5.5.0, which was released on 20-Jun-2013](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.0).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have 2 `else` after each other.

I understand that you want to give seperate error messages when the username is wrong and when the password is wrong, so you should use a different IF.

I also assume you login with the email address.

```
if($username==$dbusername&&sha1($password)==$dbpassword){

    echo "you are in";
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
}
if($username!=$dbusername&&sha1($password)!=$dbpassword){
     echo "Password and username are wrong";
}
else{
    if($password!=$dbpassword){
        echo "Your password is incorrect!";
    }

    if($username!=$dbusername){
        die("That user does not exist!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `$password!=$dbpassword` and `$username!=$dbusername`, right?